# Characterizing an anlytical function by its value on the real line

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Quote from Strichartz's book "A guide to distribution theory and fourier transform", Chap 4

> But an analtic function is determined by its values for z real

Why is that so??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity theorem for analytic functions says that if two analytic functions on a domain $D$ are equal on a set which has an accumulation point, then they are equal on $D$.

This implies that given an entire function $f$, if $g$ is an entire function so that $f=g$ on $\mathbb R$ then $f=g$ on $\mathbb C$.